# Filtering Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 2 columns as below:

```
Index Year        Country
0     2015        US
1     2015        US
2     2015        UK
3     2015        Indonesia
4     2015        US
5     2016        India
6     2016        India
7     2016        UK
```

I want to create a new dataframe containing the maximum count of country in every year.
The new dataframe will contain 3 columns as below:

```
    Index      Year      Country     Count
    0          2015      US          3
    1          2016      India       2
```

Is there any function in pandas where this can be done quickly?

Answer (score 1):

One way can be to use `groupby` and along with `size` for finding in each category adn sort values and slice by possible number of year. You can try the following:

```
num_year = df['Year'].nunique()
new_df = df.groupby(['Year', 'Country']).size().rename('Count').sort_values(ascending=False).reset_index()[:num_year]
```

Result:

```
   Year   Country  Count
0  2015      US      3
1  2016   India      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

**1.**

First get count of each pairs `Year` and `Country` by [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html).
Then get index of max value by [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) and select row by `loc`:

---

```
df = df.groupby(['Year','Country']).size()
df = df.loc[df.groupby(level=0).idxmax()].reset_index(name='Count')
print (df)
   Year Country  Count
0  2015      US      3
1  2016   India      2
```

**2.**

Use custom function with [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.head.html):

```
df = df.groupby('Year')['Country']
       .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().head(1))
       .rename_axis(('Year','Country'))
       .reset_index(name='Count')

print (df)
   Year Country  Count
0  2015      US      3
1  2016   India      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just provide a method without `groupby`

```
Count=pd.Series(list(zip(df2.Year,df2.Country))).value_counts()
          .head(2).reset_index(name='Count')
Count[['Year','Country']]=Count['index'].apply(pd.Series)
Count.drop('index',1)


Out[266]: 
   Count  Year Country
0      3  2015      US
1      2  2016   India
```